# Incrementing an integer in javascript results in NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, auto-increment

I've tried to debug this but I just don't understand why the variable disp returns as NaN whenever I increment it by one. If anyone could shed some light on why this is happening I'd appreciate it tenfold.

```
var votePages = new Array();
votePages[0] = "http://minecraftservers.org/vote/100924";
votePages[1] = "http://www.planetminecraft.com/server/revolutionarycraft---ssdfactionsecosurvivalgrief/vote/";
votePages[2] = "http://minecraftservers.net/server/66267/vote/";
votePages[3] = "http://mineservers.com/server/11885/vote";
votePages[4] = "https://minestatus.net/92187-revolutionary-craft/vote";
var disp = 0;

$("#dispVotePage").attr("src", votePages[disp]);

$(document).on('click', '#next', function(){
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", '');
    var disp = disp++;
    alert(disp);
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", votePages[disp]);
    if (disp !== 0) {
        $("#previous").css('display', 'block');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#previous', function(){
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", '');
    var disp = disp--;
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", votePages[disp]);
    if (disp === 0) {
        $("#previous").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

You'll see that I have alert(disp) in there, its for debugging purposes.

Comment: var disp = disp++; Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-declaration of `disp`. You are declaring it twice:

```
var disp = 0;                  //Initial Declaration (Global)

... <snip> ...

$(document).on('click', '#next', function(){
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", '');
    var disp = disp++;         //Re-declaration. Declares `disp` as a new local variable.
    alert(disp);
    $("#dispVotePage").attr("src", votePages[disp]);
    if (disp !== 0) {
        $("#previous").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Solution: To use the global `disp`, do not declare it again. Just use `disp++`

Comment: Yes, `undefined++` is `NaN`.

Comment: disp = disp++ doesnt work either it just needs to be disp++ but thanks yea, +1'd

Comment: @George: Good point! Updated answer. `disp = disp++` is a post increment, hence the value applied to `disp` was the unincremented value of `disp`. (PS: Kindly mark this post as `Answer`, if you're satisfied)

Comment: You don't need `disp=`, `disp++` already means `disp = disp + 1`.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Agreed. Life will be easier that way. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are declaring a new disp variable in your functions, even though you have already done so after your array at the top. Get rid of the var disp and just increment or decrement it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is probably due to
`var disp = disp++`
try `disp=disp+1` (without a var) instead. And similarly for decrements. I think it should fix this!