# Need details on scope example

Tags: javascript, scope, nested

I'm learning about scope in JS and I'm stuck on an example:

```
function one() {
 var a = 1;
 console.log(a);

  function two() {
   var a = a + 2;
   console.log(a);
   }

 two();

}

one();
```

Running this will output **NAN**.
Can you explain why it doesn't take variable ***a*** from function ***one()*** and instead chooses to define it again ? I know that ***var*** defines it again, but conidering it's a nested function why it doesn't use the variable from parent?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

As far as I've understood, and correct me if I'm wrong, same variable name can appear in different scope

```
 function one() {
 var a = 1;
 console.log( a );
}
function two() {
 var a = 2;  
 console.log( a );
}
one();   
two();
```

Also I know that code in one scope can access variables of either that scope or any scope outside of it

```
 function one() {
 var a = 1;
  function two() {
   var b = 2;
   console.log( a + b );  
  }  
 two();
 console.log( a );         
 }
 one();
```

That's why I get confused

Comment: it doesn't use it because you hide it with the local variable `a`, local scope before global scope.

Comment: Related: [Incrementing an integer in javascript results in NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19599616/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that **var** defines it again, but conidering it's a nested function why it doesn't use the variable from parent?

Because...`var` defines it again, in a nested scope. That means the `a` within `two` is not the same `a` as within `one`; it's a different variable that *shadows* (hides) `one`'s `a`, so `two` can't use it.

So now we know it's a different variable, let's look at why you get `NaN` from `two`'s `console.log`: The line

```
var a = a + 2;
```

is treated like this:

```
var a;
a = a + 2;
```

and a newly-declared variable with no initializer has the value `undefined` by default. `undefined + 2` is `NaN`.

If we change `two` to *not* shadow `a`, `two` can indeed use `a`:

```js
function one() {
    var a = 1;
    console.log(a);

    function two() {
        var b = a + 2;  // Note declaring b, and using a
        console.log(b);
    }

    two();
}

one();
```

Comment: As far as I've understood, and correct me if I'm wrong, same variable name can appear in different scope

`function one() {
  var a = 1;
  console.log( a );
}
function two() {
  var a = 2;  
  console.log( a );
}
one();   
two();`

Also I know that code in one scope can access variables of either that scope or any scope outside of it

`function one() {
  var a = 1;
  function two() {
    var b = 2;
    console.log( a + b );  
  }  
  two();
  console.log( a );         
}
one();`

That's why I get confused

Comment: @VladU: Yes, you can use the same name in nested scopes, but when you do (as I said above), you're defining a new, separate, variable and preventing access to the one in the outer scope. And yes, also as I said above, `two` can access `one`'s `a` variable if it *doesn't* shadow it.